# Where do I put meta description in my website?

Tags: html, meta

My question about web design

**Where do I put meta description in my website?**

and how can to make it strong

Comment: You should attempt to search online before asking beginner questions.  Additionally, this isn't really on-topic for StackOverflow.  Consider reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Meta data goes in the head of your html document

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Website Name</title>
<meta name="description" content="Website Description">
<meta name="keywords" content="keywords">
</head>
</html>
```